# NoMethodError in Pages#dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a dashboard for my app but when i want to display the reviews I get the NoMethodError although i have defined the variables in the controller. I am getting the error when I view the dashboard page. Here's my code

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:dashboard]

  def about
  end

  def help
  end

  def contact
  end

def dashboard
  @user = current_user
  @places = @user.places
  @reviews = @user.reviews
end

end
```

**reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_place
  before_action :authenticate_user!



  # GET /reviews/new
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  # GET /reviews/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.place_id = @place.id
    @review.save
    redirect_to place_path(@place)
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @review, notice: 'Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reviews_url, notice: 'Review was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

  def set_place    
  unless @place = Place.where(id: params[:place_id]).first
    redirect_to places_path, flash: {alert: "Place doesn't exists"}
  end
end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:comment,:rating)
    end
end
```

**places_controller.rb**

```
class PlacesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_place, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! , except: [:index,:show]

  # GET /places
  # GET /places.json
  def index
    @places = Place.all
  end

  # GET /places/1
  # GET /places/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(place_id: @place.id)
  end

  # GET /places/new
  def new
    @place = Place.new
  end

  # GET /places/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /places
  # POST /places.json
  def create
    @place = Place.new(place_params)
    @place.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.save
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /places/1
  # PATCH/PUT /places/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @place.update(place_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @place, notice: 'Place was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @place }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @place.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /places/1
  # DELETE /places/1.json
  def destroy
    @place.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to places_url, notice: 'Place was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_place
      @place = Place.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def place_params
      params.require(:place).permit(:name, :address, :description, :phone, :website)
    end
end
```

**/pages/dashboard.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">


</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
<h3>My Places</h3>

<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @places.each do |place| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= place.name %></td>
          <td><%= time_ago_in_words(place.created_at) %> ago</td>
          <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_place_path(place) %>|<%= link_to "Destroy", place_path(place), method: :delete %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
<%= link_to "New Place", new_place_path %>
</div>


<h3>My Reviews</h3>
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Place</th>
          <th>Created</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= review.place.name %></td>
          <td><%= time_ago_in_words(review.created_at) %> ago</td>
          <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_review_path(review) %>|<%= link_to "Destroy", review_path(review), method: :delete %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot :

[image]

Did anyone had this issue before ?

Comment: Please show the full stack trace and where are you getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that you are having is that the place is nil. 
you can add a a try method like this

`<td><%= review.place.try(:name) %></td>`

Answer (score 0):

The review has no associated places. So, You should implement a check before attempting to render it.

Try this:

```
<td><%= review.try(:place).try(:name) %></td>
```

Comment: why are you trying if there is a place?

Comment: @MZaragoza I believe the screenshot displays an error suggesting there is no place?

Comment: place is **nil** and there is no **name** for nil class.  so you should be ok with just having 1 try `review.place.try(:name)` as there will always be a place even if its a nil value